# How can I configure a message I sent on Slack to be editable by anyone in the Slack workspace?

Tags: slack

How can I configure a message I sent on Slack to be editable by anyone in the Slack workspace? (like a wiki answer on Stack Exchange)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for, is possible using [Slack posts](https://slack.com/intl/en-us/help/articles/203950418-Use-posts-in-Slack).

1. Click on the lightning bolt icon in the bottom left of the message window.
2. Under Slack, select Create a post.
3. Enter a title and begin typing. Your post will be saved automatically.

[image: Create a new post in Slack]

4. You can change the privacy settings of the post by clicking on the privacy status, in the top left of the window. This opens up a new dialogue where you can decide where do you want to share this post and who can edit it.

[image: Change sharing settings for a post]